# Generative RNN: how to deal with frequent characters?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to create a generative character LSTM-Network. The idea is: the model takes the last 32 existing characters and generates another one based on them. And again and again.

Here's the *model*, it's pretty simple:

```py
model = Sequential([
    Input(shape=[32, 1]),
    LSTM(64, return_sequences=True),
    LSTM(64),
    Dense(len(corpus.keys()), activation='softmax', use_bias=False),
])
```

The problem is: the frequency of characters in texts is monstrously different. The least frequent letter appears 326 times, while the most frequent - 56190. Just look at the bar plot.

[image]

Even after 200 epochs of training, all the model can predict is **space**, because it's just the most frequent character. Thus the loss is decreasing during training.

---

I've already tried more complex and simple models, and the results is always the same. The model simply remembers the frequency.

**EDIT:** here's the [notebook](https://github.com/Yoskutik/_char_rnn/blob/master/Untitled.ipynb)

Comment: You should weigh the loss based on frequency. The weight of loss for a character can simply be the inverse of frequency, or other functions built on the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from addressing the problem of overfitting, you should *sample* from the output probabilities rather than taking the highest probability (argmax). There is a Tensorflow [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_generation) which covers that.

> To get actual predictions from the model you need to sample from the output distribution, to get actual character indices. This distribution is defined by the logits over the character vocabulary.

> Note: It is important to sample from this distribution as taking the argmax of the distribution can easily get the model stuck in a loop.

This is *roughly* how you can do it:

```
example_batch_predictions = model(X_test)

sampled_indices = tf.random.categorical(example_batch_predictions[0], 
                                        num_samples=1)
sampled_indices = tf.squeeze(sampled_indices,axis=-1).numpy()
```

```
array([41, 60,  3, 31, 47, 21, 61,  6, 56, 42, 39, 40, 52, 60, 37, 37, 27,
       11,  6, 56, 64, 62, 43, 42,  6, 34,  1, 30, 16, 45, 46, 11, 17,  8,
       26,  8,  1, 46, 37, 21, 37, 53, 34, 49,  5, 58, 11,  9, 42, 62, 14,
       56, 56, 30, 31, 32, 63, 53, 10, 23, 35,  5, 19, 19, 46,  3, 23, 63,
       61, 11, 57,  0, 35, 48, 32,  4, 37,  7, 48, 23, 39, 30, 20, 26,  1,
       52, 57, 23, 46, 56, 11, 22,  7, 47, 16, 27, 38, 51, 55, 28])
```

That would be for text generation. For better training, I suggest you use an embedding layer before the LSTM:

```
model = Sequential([
    Input(shape=[32, 1]),
    Embedding(input_dim=len(corpus.keys()), output_dim=16),
    LSTM(64, return_sequences=True),
    LSTM(64),
    Dense(len(corpus.keys()), activation='softmax', use_bias=False),
])
```

This will work if you have sequences of characters, and *not* one hot encoded words.

Here's a [tutorial](https://github.com/nicolas-gervais/tensorflow-dump/blob/master/dinosaur-names-character-level-rnn) I made doing character-based text generation. Maybe it can help you.

Comment: As I understand, you talk about predicting. But my model even couldn't train. Then loss has decreased from `3.2653` to `3.2489`.

Comment: Thank you. But adding the `Embedding` layer didn't help

Comment: I think you'll have to provide more details because character-level RNNs are one of the simplest tasks. How did the loss decrease because of the embedding layer? It's virtually impossible that it doesn't help. I'm suspecting something went very wrong somewhere, which I can't see from the code you included

Comment: With embedding layer loss has decreased to 3.1123 (which is still a big number). What kind of details should I provide?

Comment: I added a link to the notebook in the question